# Is there a way to restore a Titanium backup from PC to a crashed ROM?

Tags: boot-loop, restore, windows, titanium-backup

If I have complete Titanium backup copied to my PC (where I imagine the ROM is copied too).

More than 200 files.

Now I have a crashed ROM (boot looping).

Is there a simple way to restore this backup to my phone via USB without installing a new ROM (nor TWRP)?

Comment: TB doesn't backup ROMs, it only backs up applications.

Comment: How to backup the entire device (ROM + everything) to a PC?

Comment: Use TWRP to create a Nandroid backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't install TWRP, what about booting it for once?

Download a valid TWRP image and reboot your phone into bootloader, and run on computer:

```
fastboot boot twrp.img
```

Then you can use `adb push` to transfer the files.